# How to Get Xcode to Properly Compile After "Undeleting" Files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I accidentally deleted a set of files from my project (.h, .m, .xib).

After adding them back into the project from backup, I get errors compiling. It looks like the linker is stuck trying to reference an old .o file from the deleted source:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SNDYTheUndeletedViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SNDYParentViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I clear this error? I've tried:

- doing a "Clean"
- restarting Xcode
- forcing a recompile of the Parent View Controller (by changing some code around, then changing back)
- deleting Derived Data
- changing the Derived Data folder from "Default" to "Relative"

The last time I did this, I just created a new view controller with a different name. I'd like to avoid that and actually just address this issue.

Comment: You need to reset the target membership of each file your restored.

Comment: Thanks! Should I just delete this question (unless you want the rep)?

Comment: Leave it. It will help someone else someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rmaddy stated in the comment to my question, reset the target membership of each file restored:

1. Highlight the file(s) in the Project Navigator (cmd-1).
2. Open the File Inspector Utility pane (cmd-opt-1).
3. In the "Target Membership" section of the pane, click the checkbox for the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing project reference from xcode repositories.

Goto File -> Source control -> Repositories..

delete all the project references under Repositories and Projects.